# Underground in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am doing a practice in Prolog, and I need do a program that say the way to go from a station, to other station, in Madrid Underground (Metro de Madrid).

I have a file to data (datos.pl), and other file with program (programa.pl). In data file, I write knowledge base. For example:

```
linea(2, cuatro_caminos). linea(2, canal). linea(2, quevedo). linea(2, san_bernardo). linea(2, noviciado). linea(2, santo_domingo). linea(2, opera). linea(2, sol). linea(2, sevilla). linea(2, banco_de_espana). linea(2, retiro). linea(2, principe_de_vergara). linea(2, goya). linea(2, manuel_becerra). linea(2, ventas).

linea(3, moncloa). linea(3, arguelles). linea(3, ventura_rodriguez). linea(3, plaza_de_espana). linea(3, callao). linea(3, sol). linea(3, lavapies). linea(3, embajadores). linea(3, palos_de_la_frontera). linea(3, delicias). linea(3, legazpi).

arista(2, cuatro_caminos, canal). arista(2, canal, quevedo). arista(2, quevedo, san_bernardo). arista(2, san_bernardo, noviciado). arista(2, noviciado, santo_domingo). arista(2, santo_domingo, opera). arista(2, opera, sol). arista(2, sol, sevilla). arista(2, sevilla, banco_de_espana). arista(2, banco_de_espana, retiro). arista(2, retiro, principe_de_vergara). arista(2, principe_de_vergara, goya). arista(2, goya, manuel_becerra). arista(2, manuel_becerra, ventas).

arista(3, moncloa, arguelles). arista(3, arguelles, ventura_rodriguez). arista(3, ventura_rodriguez, plaza_de_espana). arista(3, plaza_de_espana, callao). arista(3, callao, sol). arista(3, sol, lavapies). arista(3, lavapies, embajadores). arista(3, embajadores, palos_de_la_frontera). arista(3, palos_de_la_frontera, delicias). arista(3, delicias, legazpi).
```

In my program file:

```
:- consult(['datos.pl']).

camino(A, A, _, [A]).

camino(A, B, Visitados, [A|Resto]):-
   (arista(_, A, ASig); arista(_, ASig, A)),
   not(member(ASig, Visitados)),
   camino(ASig, B, [ASig|Visitados], Resto).
```

When I consult to Prolog, for example "camino(sol, goya, [], L).", I receive various response:

```
L = [sol, sevilla, banco_de_espana, retiro, principe_de_vergara, goya] ;
...
L = [sol, callao, opera, sol, sevilla, banco_de_espana, retiro, principe_de_vergara, goya] ;
...
```

The problem is that "L" content two instances of "sol". I don't know where is the problem. I think that don't build the way well.

Answer (score 5):

There's an edge-case in your solution: The very first station (i.e, sol), is never pushed into the `Visitados` list.  Therefore, this specific station is not protected from repetition by the condition `not(member(...))`.  Changing the query to `camino(sol, goya, [sol], L).` gives the expected results.  I suggest add this predicate:

```
camino(A, B, L) :-
  camino(A, B, [A], L).
```